# JAVA JDBC Driver PostgreSQL: Parse numbers encoded as BYTEA object

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, blob, bytea

I have relation where for each record there is BYTEA column (UTF-8) encoding 3 numbers in the following order:

bytes 0-1: number 1

bytes 2-3: number 2

bytes 4-6: number 3

How can I parse the binary data to readable numbers?

Currently I have this and don't know how to continue:

```
Class.forName(dbDriver);
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, dbUser, dbPass);
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
String query = "SELECT ...";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
while (rs.next()) {
    byte[] data = rs.getBytes(1);
    //TODO Parse
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: You seem to use byte 4 twice. I assumed that's a typo, and that number 3 is from bytes 5-6, not 4-6, i.e. 2 bytes long, same as number 1 and 2.

Comment: @Andreas Hi, my mistake. I edited. the first 2 are 2 bytes, the third is 3 bytes and can be negative.

Comment: If only the third number can be negative, then you really need to define the number format better. E.g. are the numbers stored in binary? If yes, are signed numbers stored in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)? Or is the sign stored as a byte by itself? If not binary, are the numbers stored as text? Or [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) (packed or unpacked)? Or something else?

Comment: @Andreas unfortunately I don't have all these info in the spec. Is there a common practice here?

Comment: Not with a 3-byte number, no, there is no common practice. I'd suggest you get some examples of the `byte[7]` values, and look at the bytes. Helps if the examples also show what 3 numbers they represent.

Comment: @Andreas got it thanks, will wait for the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how the numbers are stored.
Are they binary?
Are they [signed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)?
Are they big or little [endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?

Assuming yes to the first two, you can use bit-manipulation, e.g.

```
// Little-endian
short num1 = (short) ((data[0] & 0xFF) | (data[1] & 0xFF) << 8);

// Big-endian
short num1 = (short) ((data[0] & 0xFF) << 8 | (data[1] & 0xFF));
```

But it's probably easier to use [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html):

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
short num1 = buf.getShort();
short num2 = buf.getShort();
short num3 = buf.getShort();
```

`ByteBuffer` is `BIG_ENDIAN` by default.

Comment: using ByteBuffer, where I specify that the first 2 numbers consists out of 2 bytes and the third one out of 3? Also, the numbers can be negative, is it matters?

Comment: `ByteBuffer` does not have a method for getting 3 bytes as a number. It can do 1 (`get()`), 2 (`getShort()`), 4 (`getInt()`), or 8 (`getLong()`), all decoded as signed two's-complement binary numbers *("signed" means value can be negative)*. If you need a 3-byte number, use bit-manipulation, but I doubt you do (see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227220/java-jdbc-driver-postgresql-parse-numbers-encoded-as-bytea-object/44227352?noredirect=1#comment75465770_44227220)).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

For String :

```
    String tatto = "my tatto"; //for example
    byte[] array = tatto.getBytes(); // Or any bytes
    String s = new String(array);
    System.out.println(s);
```

For byte[] :

```
    byte[] data = new byte[]{ 1, 16, 84, 2, 101, 110, 83, 111};
    long val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
       val = (val << 8) + (data[i] & 0xff);
    }
    System.out.println(val);
```

Comment: Hi I get  java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString

Comment: Calling `toString()` on a `byte[]` will produce something like `[B@15db9742`.

Comment: That's right you will get byte[] from db but we don't know what the type of data before storing.

Comment: What does updated answer have to do with getting 3 numbers from a `byte[6]` array, stored as 2 bytes per number?

Comment: What does "For byte[] :" section, which gets *one* number from a `byte[8]` array, have to do with getting **three** numbers from a `byte[6]` array?